# Finding length of an array stored in an .json file

Tags: javascript, json

i wanted to create a id for my list of objects which i am storing it in a .json file(just wanted it as a dummy database which stored info), i wanted to give the id as 1,2,3,4... for each object created, for this i wanted to find the length of the array in the .json file hence i use the code shown below

```
var idNo = ()=>{
    fs.readFile('xyz.json','utf-8',(err,data)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        const xyz = JSON.parse(data);
        return xyz.length + 1;
        
    });
};
```

edit: i have tried correcting the code and now the id is generated something like

```
    let idNo = ()=>{
    fs.readFile("xyz.json", "utf-8" , (err,data)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        try{
            if(JSON.parse(data)[0] == null) return 0;
            return JSON.parse(data)[JSON.parse(data).length].id + 1;

        }
        catch(err){
            throw err;
        }

    })
}
```

and to then store the a new set of object i have done something like this (also the parseInt(idNo++) is done because idNo is not accepted when given to the key id)

```
    const newxyz = {
    id: parseInt(idNo++),
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description
  };
  fs.readFile("xyz.json",'utf-8',(err,data)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    const todo = JSON.parse(data);
    todo.push(newxyz);
    fs.writeFile("xyz.json",JSON.stringify(newxyz),(err)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
      });
  });
```

Comment: You can't return your id like this: your `return` is inside the callback function for `readFile`, so it will return the value from the callback function. At this point, your main id function has already returned `undefined`. You must either provide a callback function for you id function, or use the sync version `readFileSync`

Comment: is `xyz` an Array, then your code seems fine, except nothing will be returned from `idNo` of course, since you're returning nothing in that function

Comment: *"is my code syntaxically wrong"*: I don't understand why you would ask this. Syntax is checked and reported by your JavaScript environment. Did it say the syntax was wrong? Then it is wrong. It didn't? Then it has no syntax errors.

Comment: i noted my mistaked pointed by @Kaddath, my new code now is `var todoArray = fs.readFileSync('todo.json').toJSON;`  and then i create a new object as where the id key is created as id: `xyz.length `but still the id is always 0 when corrected, what is the mistake?

Comment: @trincot thanks for pointing out that mistake, hope the edited version is more meaningful

Comment: It's hard without seeing the whole corrected code, maybe you can add it to the question (don't remove the original code). Be careful also that if you use such custom code, you will maybe run into id conflicts later (what happens when the function is called twice at the same time?). Usually databases apply different sorts of locks to prevent concurrence problems, with your code you risk to have duplicate entries

Comment: @Kaddath i have posted the relevant codes in the OP, this version too doesnt work much

Comment: `anyArray[anyArray.length]` is always going to be outside the bounds of the array, which are from 0 to length - 1.

Comment: @James there is not really a notion of array out of bounds in javascript, you can write `var a = []; a[1000] = 'test';` it will work, you just will have 1000 rows at `undefined` before `'test'`

Comment: Sorry @Kaddath for the confusion, what I mean is no array produced by JSON.parse will have an element at index array.length (rather it will be undefined), like the line starting `return JSON.parse(…)`

Comment: @James you're right, I hadn't seen that the OP accesses one index too far on the second code example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the length of the json file based data and also can append the id in it, check below code,

```js
function Func() {
    fetch("https://dummyjson.com/products")
        .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data.products.length);
        console.log(data); 
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>JSON data length</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div role="button" onclick="Func()">Click Here</div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like I hinted in the comments, you cannot return the value from the callback function like this, because the callback is a different function, the flow would be:

- start of the main function
- launch the async readFile
- return from the main function (value `undefined` because there is no `return`)
- [asynchronous operations of readFile]
- start of the readFile callback
- return the id to readFile, which does nothing (readFile doesn't expect a result)

You have the choice of either use a callback function for your id method (recommended because sync functions block the thread)

```
var idNo = (callback)=>{
    fs.readFile('xyz.json','utf-8',(err,data)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        try{
            const xyz = JSON.parse(data);
            callback(xyz.length); //or xyz.length + 1 if your ids are 1-indexed
        }catch(e){
            //invalid JSON, either throw(e); or callback(0); depending on use case (or callback(1); if 1-indexed)
        }
    });
};

idNo((id)=>{
    //do something with the id
});
```

or:

```
var idNo = ()=>{
    var data = fs.readFileSync('xyz.json','utf-8');
    try{
        const xyz = JSON.parse(data);
        return xyz.length; //or xyz.length + 1 if your ids are 1-indexed
    }catch(e){
        //invalid JSON, either throw(e); or return 0; depending on use case (or return 1; if 1-indexed)
    }
};

var id = idNo();
//do something with the id
```

You also have the possibility to use the promise based API and have the best of both worlds (non thread blocking file read without having to use a callback) with `await`, but that would require importing fsPromise instead of fs

CAUTION: Be careful also that if you use such custom code for ids, you will maybe run into id conflicts later (what happens when the function is called twice at the same time?). Usually databases apply different sorts of locks to prevent concurrence problems, with your code you risk to have duplicate entries problems if different instances access the file at the same moment